React Native stack navigation — back button icon not visible on iOS
I'm using:
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.12",
"react-native": "^0.74.2",

As the title says — the back button chevron on iOS is invisible for some iOS users. Personally I can't reproduce the issue (on physical iPad, iOS Simulator, nor Android), but my user testers have this on a variety of iPhone models. Tapping the area where the icon should be does work as the back button, the icon is just not visible.
My screenOptions:
const globalScreenOptions = {
  headerShown: true,
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#eee',
  },
  headerTintColor: '#1f1f1f',
  headerTitleStyle: {
    fontFamily: 'Encode',
    fontWeight: 'semibold',
    fontSize: 22,
    textAlign: 'left',
  },
  headerBackTitleVisible: false,
  headerTitleAlign: 'left',
};

Things I've tried after online research:

Remove 1.5x icon files from stack nav node_modules
react-native-fix-image

These didn't solve the issue.
Any ideas?
EDIT: No solutions at time of writing, in case anyone has this same issue — I'm now using a custom back arrow image in headerLeft and giving it back functionality on press.
